# Breaking up a large string into parts

Tags: javascript

I have multiple strings as below -

```
var str1 = "this is a test that goes on and on"+param1
var str2 = "this is also a test this is also"+param2+" a test this is also a test this is also a tes" 
var str3 = "this is also a test"
```

I'm assigning each string into its own var so as to keep the code readable and prevent the string values from trailing across the string. Also as I have read that the newline javascript character does not work in all browsers - 
[Creating multiline strings in JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/805107/multiline-strings-in-javascript)

I then concat the strings -

```
var concatStr = str1 + str2 + str3
```

and return the string concatenated value.

Is this an acceptable method of breaking up a large string into into its parts. Or can it be improved ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There's no need to assign each line to a different variable:

```
var str1 = "this is a test that goes on and on"+param1 +
     "this is also a test this is also"+param2+
     " a test this is also a test this is also a tes" +
     "this is also a test";
```

Personally, I'd do the following:

```
var string = ['hello ', param1,
              'some other very long string',
              'and another.'].join('');
```

For me, it's easier to type out, and read.

Answer (score 1):

If you use really long string, then hold parts of it in an array and then join them:

```
ARRAY = ['I', 'am', 'joining', 'the', 'array', '!'];
ARRAY.join(' ');
```

and the result:

```
"I am joining the array !"
```

Keep in mind, that if you need to do this in Client-Side JavaScript, then probably you'r doing something wrong. :)

Answer (score 0):

You can use an array. Its join method is fastest way to concatenate strings.

```
var myArray = [
   "this is a test that goes on and on"+param1,
   "this is also a test this is also"+param2+" a test this is also a test this is also a tes",
   "this is also a test"
];
```

and then use:

```
myArray.join('');
```

to get your complete string.